# Create UISegementControl and UIImagePicker in same UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I am creating a `UISegementControl` in `UIPopoverController`. How can i add `UIImagePicker` in that same `UIPopoverController`.

```
segmentController *segmentCtrl = [[segmentController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:segmentCtrl];

UIImagePickerController *imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[imgPicker setDelegate:self];

UIPopoverController *popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navCtrl];
[popOver setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 500) animated:YES];
popOver.delegate = self;
self.popoverImageViewController = popOver;
[self.popoverImageViewController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:button permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

In the above code It's create a `UISegementControl` in UIPopoverController. But i need to add also UIImagePicker in that UIPopover...

If i made any mistake. Please correct me.

Comment: did u try setting the imagePicker source as either camera or gallery? and how would you set the rootviewcontroller as segmentControl?

Comment: Yup, i had gallery in that imagePicker

Comment: I am creating a segmentcontrol as UIViewController in other file.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this.

```
imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

UIViewController *containerController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
containerController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(768, 1000);

NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];

[containerController.view addSubview:imagePickerController.view];
[containerController.view addSubview:segmentedControl];

popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:containerController];

[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:selectedRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:4 animated:YES];

//add ur segment control on top it would take 44 px then adjust the imagePicker frame accordingly.

CGRect tFrame = containerController.view.frame;
tFrame.origin.x -= 44;
tFrame.size.height -=44;
[imagePickerController.view setFrame:containerController.view.frame];
```

Comment: Yeah, It will create a imagePicker in that Popover I am already tried. But i need to create both uiSegementControl and imagePicker in that same Popver

Comment: Yup, Its work fine But i click the imagePicker this error while comes "UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent is not available on this device" and also the imagePicker will hide.

Comment: That's weird we are presenting the imagePicker in a UIPopOver not as modal VC right?

Comment: Sorry i can't understand :(